# Minha classe em Python está funcionado mas tem os valores do resultado não batem

Tags: python

Estou criando uma classe de Conta Corrente. Nesta classe quero ter o saldo de cada conta e a totalização de todas as contas, mas está dando erro no saldo da segunda conta, a classe está pegando o saldo da primeira conta.

Função que imprime o resultado:

```
def imprimeSaldos():
    print('-' * 30)
    print(f'Itau Credito: {itau.conta} ->> {itau.totalCredito}')
    print(f'Itau Debito.: {itau.conta} ->> {itau.totalDebito}')
    print(f'Itau Saldo..: {itau.conta} ->> {itau.saldo}')

    print('-' * 30)
    print(f'Caixa Credito: {caixa.conta} ->> {caixa.totalCredito}')
    print(f'Caixa Debito.: {caixa.conta} ->> {caixa.totalDebito}')
    print(f'Caixa Saldo..: {caixa.conta} ->> {caixa.saldo}')

    print('-' * 30)
    print(f'Total de Credito: {Conta.totalCredito}')
    print(f'Total de Credito: {Conta.totalDebito}')
    print(f'Saldo...........: {Conta.saldo}')
```

A minha classe:

```
class Conta(object):
    totalCredito = 0
    totalDebito = 0
    conta = ''
    saldo = 0

    def __init__(self, pConta = 0, pSaldo = 0):
        # Alimenta os valores da cota
        self.conta = pConta
        self.totalCredito += pSaldo
        self.saldo = pSaldo

        # Alimenta os valores totais da classe
        Conta.totalCredito += pSaldo
        Conta.saldo = Conta.totalCredito - Conta.totalDebito

    def Deposito(self, pValor = 0):
        # Alimenta os valores da cota
        self.totalCredito += pValor

        # Alimenta os valores totais da classe
        Conta.totalCredito += pValor
        Conta.saldo = Conta.totalCredito - Conta.totalDebito

    def Saque(self, pValor = 0):
        # Alimenta os valores da cota
        self.totalDebito += pValor

        # Alimenta os valores totais da classe
        Conta.totalDebito += pValor
        Conta.saldo = Conta.totalCredito - Conta.totalDebito
```

Instâncias das minhas contas:

```
itau = Conta('123-4', 50)
caixa = Conta('321-0', 0)
```

Resultado das contas:

```
------------------------------
Itau Credito: 123-4 ->> 50
Itau Debito.: 123-4 ->> 0
Itau Saldo..: 123-4 ->> 50
------------------------------
Caixa Credito: 321-0 ->> 50
Caixa Debito.: 321-0 ->> 0
Caixa Saldo..: 321-0 ->> 0
------------------------------
Total de Credito: 50
Total de Credito: 0
Saldo...........: 50
```

Vejam que mesmo eu passando 0 (zero) para a conta da caixa,
ela ficou com 50 reis de Crédito.

Isto está errado não é mesmo?

Comment: Soluções ao problema não devem estar na pergunta. A resposta deve ser postada como resposta. Sua pergunta foi fechada como duplicata porque já possui respostas em outros tópicos. Se discorda do fechamento, por favor [edit] a pergunta e esclarecer qual é a diferença do seu problema para os demais. Aproveitando, o que fez como "solução" não é solução para o problema. Recomendo que leia as perguntas citadas e entenda qual é, de fato, o problema e pesquise sobre o que é atributos de classe e de instância no Python.

Comment: Não sei onde fica a opção de responder a essa pergunta. Gostaria de ter respondido postando a solução que encontrei. Mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: Não consegue responder porque a pergunta foi fechada. Se acha que ela responde seu problema, ela também deverá responder as perguntas citadas, então poderia responder por elas e não aqui. Você chegou a pesquisar sobre atributos de instância e de classe?

Comment: Sim. Pesquisei. Entendi que o que eu estava fazendo estava errado. Então descobri que os atributos da instancia não tinha nada a ver com com os atributos da classe.